# how to find the starting and ending index of a span in a document in spacy

Tags: nlp, spacy

I am doing some NLP work using spacy. I have a sentence and a noun chunk, how to find the starting word index and ending word index of the noun chunk using spacy?
As for instance, If I have "I live in New York City", and the noun chunk is "New York", then I want 3 as the output

Comment: spacy will consider `New York City` as a single noun chunk.

Answer (score 0):

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
text="I live in New York City"
doc = nlp(text)

#To find the Noun chunks

Noun_chunks= [chunk.text for chunk in doc.noun_chunks]

#for loop to find the index of noun chunks

for noun in Noun_chunks:
  starting_index = text.index(noun)
  ending_index = text.index(noun) + len(noun) - 1
  print(noun,starting_index,ending_index)

#output
#There are 2 noun_chunks: I and New York City
#I 0 0 (starting at 0 and ending at 0)
#New York City 10 22 (starting at 10 and ending at 22)
```